# PayPal is not sending IPN’s to listener

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn

I have setup IPN URL under notifications on my Sandbox account. When I do test payment and nothing found under IPN history. **its seems Sandbox PayPal is not sending IPN’s to listener**. When i did test using IPN Simulator and it works fine.

Any ides why it's not working

Comment: Is your site using https ? (or not ?)

Comment: yes. i am using https. it was working fine yesterday

Comment: So it was working fine yesterday, but it is not working today ???? (so there is an error which is time-dependent ?) ... `First step:` check whether your SSL cert has just expired

Comment: No. Even I tested with using IPN Simulator and  its working fine..  but when tranction happens Paypal is not sending to listenser. IPN history is empty

Comment: same thing here. Paypal is not sending the IPN, IPN history is empty. Did you try only Sandbox or also real paypal?

Comment: Okay I tested it with the real paypal (not the sandbox) and the real paypal is sending the IPN.

Comment: @AllamandaWeitgereist yes, it worked on real paypal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whats an example of a PayPal Transaction ID created in the sandbox, for which you expect to receive an IPN? Are you sure you configured IPN for the correct sandbox business account in [www.sandbox.paypal.com](http://www.sandbox.paypal.com)?  Depending on your integration method, if it is not the current v2/orders you can specify a notify_url at transaction time to override the account-level IPN setting.

But really you should just do a [Set up standard payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/set-up-standard-payments/) integration that calls your server for the v2/checkout/orders API and not need IPN at all. No reason to use that old asynchronous and clunky service.

Comment: i am using Donation button and passed notify_url and also  setup IPN setting under settigs

Comment: Well we can't advise on specifics without the sample code of your sandbox button and a sample resulting sandbox transaction ID.

Comment: Ok. Let me try to do